# Por que, quando mudo o tamanho da janela, os componentes desenhados somem?

Tags: java, swing, gui, awt

Construí uma aplicação usando o [windowbuilder](https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) do eclipse. Nela, ao clicar com o mouse, uma figura é desenhada de acordo com o último botão selecionado.

Porém, quando mudo o tamanho da janela, todos os desenhos somem.

Após ler essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380317/java-swing-drawing-disappears-when-resizing-window), esse [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), e esse [artigo](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html); suponho que devo fazer um override do método `paint(Graphics g)` e adicionar campos a uma classe que armazene os desenhos.

Mas não está claro para mim onde eu faria isto. Porque eu realmente não entendo o quê está acontecendo nos bastidores do código.

### Classe criada com windowbuilder

```
public class PintarFiguras {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    PintarFiguras window = new PintarFiguras();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public PintarFiguras() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel canvas = new JPanel();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // pegar coordenadas
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();

                Graphics g = canvas.getGraphics(); 

                Artista.desenhar(g,x,y);
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        canvas.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        frame.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton btnQuadrado = new JButton("quadrado");
        btnQuadrado.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Artista.setModo(MODOS.QUADRADO);
            }
        });
        toolBar.add(btnQuadrado);

        Component horizontalStrut = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
        toolBar.add(horizontalStrut);

        JButton btnCirculo = new JButton("circulo");
        btnCirculo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Artista.setModo(MODOS.CIRCULO);
            }
        });
        toolBar.add(btnCirculo);

        Component horizontalStrut_1 = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
        toolBar.add(horizontalStrut_1);

        JButton btnNada = new JButton("nada");
        btnNada.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Artista.setModo(MODOS.NADA);
            }
        });
        toolBar.add(btnNada);

        Component horizontalStrut_2 = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
        toolBar.add(horizontalStrut_2);

        JButton btnLimpar = new JButton("limpar");
        btnLimpar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Graphics g = canvas.getGraphics();
                g.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });
        toolBar.add(btnLimpar);
    }

}
```

### Enum das figuras a desenhar

```
public enum MODOS {
QUADRADO, CIRCULO, NADA}
```

### Classe artista, que faz os desenhos

```
public abstract class Artista {
    private static MODOS modo = MODOS.NADA;

    public static MODOS getModo() {
        return modo;
    }

    public static void setModo(MODOS modo) {
        Artista.modo = modo;
    }

    /**
     * pinta um objeto de acordo com o modo
     * https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/index.html
     */
    public static void desenhar(Graphics g, int x, int y) {     
        switch(modo){   

        case QUADRADO:
            pintarQuadrado(g,x,y);
            break;

        case CIRCULO:
            pintarCirculo(g,x,y);
            break;

        case NADA:
            break;
        }       
    }

    private static void pintarQuadrado(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 10);
    }

    private static void pintarCirculo(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.drawOval(x, y, 20, 20);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os componentes estão sumindo pois eles estão sendo só adicionados e pintados uma vez no [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html), mas não há o callback do método `paint(Graphics g)`, que é chamado sempre quando é necessário pintar a tela novamente, como no seu caso em um resize. Então quando você muda o tamanho da tela, os objetos só irão aparecer novamente quando você, pelo que eu vi no método, clicar em algum lugar da tela.

Praticamente o Java faz todo o trabalho sujo atráves do método paint e ele certifica de que os objetos vão ser desenhados após alguma mudança no painel.

Uma solução seria fazer sua classe `PintarFiguras` extender de JPanel e assim fazer o override do método paint e colocar o método `desenhar(Graphics g, int x, int y)` dentro.

Assim, no MouseListener em `mouseClicked` apenas chame o `repaint`.

Para referencia do JPanel, não é preciso criar um novo objeto, apenas chame `this` (no escopo da classe, claro)

Agora, as variáveis x e y que foram criadas dentro do `mouseClicked`, é só fazer elas no escopo da classe e atribuir os valores normalmente.

A classe `PintarFiguras` ficaria assim:

```
public class PintarFiguras extends JPanel {

private int x, y;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new PintarFiguras();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public PintarFiguras() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // pegar coordenadas
            PintarFiguras.this.x = e.getX();
            PintarFiguras.this.y = e.getY();

            repaint();
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
    frame.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JButton btnQuadrado = new JButton("quadrado");
    btnQuadrado.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Artista.setModo(MODOS.QUADRADO);
        }
    });
    toolBar.add(btnQuadrado);

    Component horizontalStrut = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
    toolBar.add(horizontalStrut);

    JButton btnCirculo = new JButton("circulo");
    btnCirculo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Artista.setModo(MODOS.CIRCULO);
        }
    });
    toolBar.add(btnCirculo);

    Component horizontalStrut_1 = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
    toolBar.add(horizontalStrut_1);

    JButton btnNada = new JButton("nada");
    btnNada.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Artista.setModo(MODOS.NADA);
        }
    });
    toolBar.add(btnNada);

    Component horizontalStrut_2 = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
    toolBar.add(horizontalStrut_2);

    JButton btnLimpar = new JButton("limpar");
    btnLimpar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            limparTela();
        }
    });
    toolBar.add(btnLimpar);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Artista.desenhar(g, this.x, this.y);
}

public void limparTela(){
    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

EDIT: como @diegofm indicou, declarei o JFrame como final dentro do escopo do método, pois assim ele poderá ser chamado normalmente dentro de classes anônimas, como usado pelo OP.

Comment: Tem um errinho no código, coisa fácil de corrigir, `frame` precisa ser final pra poder ser chamado dentro do actionlistener. Classes anônimas só acessam parâmetros de classe ou variáveis locais que sejam finais.

Comment: Arrumei, obrigado. O JFrame estava declarado como private, mas não era necessário, então passei para o escopo do método e o fiz final.

Comment: Muito boa a resposta,  +1

Comment: Eu desejo que o novo desenho não apague os antigos. Como posso armazenar os desenhos já feitos para serem repintados também? De que classe eles são, Graphics?

Comment: Você pode guardar as coordenadas e os atributos (x, y, width, height) dos desenhos, para depois desenhá-los. No caso do retângulo tem até classe que representa a forma (Rectangle). E se não me engano tem para o circulo também (Ellipse2D)